# JS - Appear & Animate

Tags: jquery-animate

I have a div which starts `display:none`. I want it to display on scroll and animate down at the top of the page (it's a fixed position menu).

I can make it display on scroll, but I can't figure out the animation.

```
$(window).scroll( function(){

    /* Check the location of each desired element */
    $('.hideme').each( function(i){

        var bottom_of_object = 120;
        var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop();

        /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it it */
        if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){

            if ($(this).css('opacity')==0) {$(this).fadeTo(0,1);}
        } else {
            if ($(this).css('opacity')==1) {$(this).fadeTo(0,0).hide();}
            }    
    }); 
});
```

I'm probably looking at `$(this).animate` but I don't really know what I'm doing and have no idea to incorporate this into my existing code. Animation required: Move top of div from top -66px to 0px.

Html:

```
<div class="hideme" style="display:none; z-index:4000; position:fixed; background-color:rgba(255, 102, 0, 0.95); top:0px; height:66px; width:100%; left:0%; border-bottom:1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)">
<A href="index"><img src="logo_01_151_45.png" alt="logo" style="position: fixed; top:10px; left:50%; margin-left:-490px"/></A>
</DIV>
```

Any assistance you can provide would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: canyou  post some html or make a fiddle on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: any css to go with that cos i can't reproduce it in a fiddle

Comment: Can get it to work on the web (mulitple browsers) but not jsfiddle. Not sure how to insert ajax into code. My header includes...

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

Sorry about this.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
/* Every time the window is scrolled ... */
$(window).scroll( function(){

    /* Check the location of each desired element */
    $('.hideme').each( function(i){

        var bottom_of_object = 120;
        var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop();

        /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it it */
        if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){

            if ($(this).css('opacity')==0) {$(this).fadeTo(0,1).animate({top:'0px'});}
        } else {
            if ($(this).css('opacity')==1) {$(this).fadeTo(0,0).hide().animate({top:'-66px'});}
            }


    }); 

});
```